# weird query behavior oracle sql - convert text to number

Tags: sql, oracle

oracle query This works

```
select *
from (
select to_number(substr(app_cluster,6,2), '99') as  b
from xtern_app_info
WHERE app_cluster IS NOT NULL
AND APP_CLUSTER <> 'CLUSTER'
);
```

[image]

but when adding 'where b > 2' makes an error, why?

```
select *
from (
select to_number(substr(app_cluster,6,2), '99') as  b
from xtern_app_info
WHERE app_cluster IS NOT NULL
AND APP_CLUSTER <> 'CLUSTER'
) where b > 2;
```

ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-01722: invalid number
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
*Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.

Comment: Are you sure that the first query returned ALL rows? Because, when you use GUI like SQL Developer or TOAD, by default they return limited number of rows (such as 100 or 500). Add DISTINCT to SELECT and check whether it ends up correctly or not. It appears that some APP_CLUSTER values on 6th and 7th position contain something different than numerics.

Comment: Regardless of anything else: app_cluster IS NOT NULL is redundant in the WHERE clause. NULL will never pass the `<>` condition anyway.